# How can I tell if there has been a significant change?

Tags: probability, distributions, statistical-significance

Say I have these performance measures on an individual:

10
5
15
9
8
7

I want to know if there is a sig. change from one data point to the next. So I want to know if the increase from 5 to 15 is sig. or I want to know if the drop from 10 to 5 is sig. What is the best way to do this?

Lets say I was training someone to throw a ball and hit a target. They had 20 attempts. They attempt it the first time and hit the target 10 times. Then there is intervention/training/guidance and they do this process again so next time they hit the target 5 times etc. How can I tell if the change in the number of accurate hits is significant?

Comment: This is often called _changepoint detection_: see [our `change-point` tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-point?sort=votes) and [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection).

Comment: Finding even a *reasonable* way to do this depends on what the measures are, how frequently they are taken, whether you need to evaluate the changes for one individual or many, and how much data you have.